# CSS - ограничить наследование по вложенности

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы например свойства селектора `div div{}` применялись только во вложениях `<div>` второго уровня, но не наследовались div-ами и другими элементами, имеющими 3-ий и более глубокие уровни вложения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
div {
  color: orange;
}
.first > div {
  color: green;
}
.second > div > div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">div 1
  <div>div 2
    <div>div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="second">div 1
  <div>div 2
    <div>div 3
      <div>div 4
        <div>div 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[webref.ru | Дочерние селекторы](https://webref.ru/css/selector/child)